# Batch File WMIC Invalid Query

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Im creating a batch that kills a process, im filtering by comandline because its a java process and they all go by "Java(TM)" as their name.

The error that im getting its "ERROR invalid query"

```
@echo off
wmic PROCESS where "ComandLine like '%C:\Program Files\Program.exe'  " CALL Terminate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
wmic process where "commandline like '%C:\\Program Files\\Program.exe'"
```

Don't forget to double the backslashes.